# React Router and History

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

Hello I'm really new to react and I'm watching this wonderful youtube ReactJs tutorial from Learncode.academy. This tutorial is from last year I don't know if these modules are already deprecated. I got these error messages:

> You have provided a history object created with history v4.x or v2.x and earlier. This version of React Router is only compatible with v3 history objects. Please change to history v3.x. at invariant Here is my code:

```
    import Layout from "./components/Layout";
    import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from "react-router";

    const app = document.getElementById('app');

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router history="{browserHistory}">
       <Route path="/" component="{Layout}">
       </Route>
      </Router>,
    app);
```

Here is my package.json

```
"history": "^3.2.1",
"react-router": "^3.0.2",
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455999/history-object-issue-with-react-router

Might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the history and the components incorrectly. You dont need quotes around the history and component objects

```
import Layout from "./components/Layout";
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from "react-router";

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
   </Route>
  </Router>,
app);
```

Comment: sometimes its hard to figure out the solution specially when  the error doesnt lead you to the right path. I hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

From  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/353

To get basename working for react-router@3.0.2:

## npm install --save react-router@3.0.2

## npm install --save history@^3.0.0

(check react-router package.json to get the correct history version to use, current major version of history is 4.x and won't work with react-router@3.0.2)

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHistory } from 'history'

const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: '/subdirectory-where-the-app-is-hosted-goes-here'
})

render((
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomeView} />
      <Route path='other-views' component={OtherViews} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('main'))
```